# create Regex for parsing

Tags: regex, parsing

I want to find a regex for the string **105-02 Neuere deutsche Literatur** which captures in groups with group 1: **105** group 2: **02** and group 3: **Neuere deutsche Literatur**

I tried it with `^(\d.*) ([^\d]*[^\d])$` but the output is 1.   `105-02 Neuere deutsche`
2.  `Literatur`

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Wiktor Yes it works :)

Comment: Great. Please consider accepting the answer to finalize the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
^(\d+)-(\d+)\s*(.*)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wH7jS4/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 matching 1+ digits
- `-` -  a literal hyphen
- `(\d+)` - Group 2 matching 1+ digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Group 3 matching the rest of the line
- `$` - end of line/string.